# If $P(|X-Y|>\frac{1}{n})=0$ $\forall n\in \Bbb N$, then $X=Y$ a.s.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables, solution-verification, almost-everywhere

> Let $X,Y$ be random variables on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$. Show that if $P(|X-Y|>(1/n))=0$ $\forall n\in \Bbb N$,then $X=Y$ almost surely.

I've tried to solve this in the following way:

Taking the limit as $n\to\infty$ on both sides of $$P(|X-Y|>(1/n))=0,$$ you get $$\lim_{n\to\infty}P(|X-Y|>(1/n))=0.$$ Since $|X-Y|>(1/n)$ is a monotone sequence, the continuity property of the probability measure $P$ yields that $$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}P(|X-Y|>(1/n))&=P(\lim_{n\to\infty}(|X-Y|>(1/n)))\\
&=P((|X-Y|>0)).
\end{align}$$
So, we have that $$P((|X-Y|>0))=\lim_{n\to\infty}P(|X-Y|>(1/n))=0,$$ which is our desired result.

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. This is correct.

Comment: Thank You @WoolierThanThou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct, there are just some minor formal issues: The monotone sequence you are referring to is the sequence of sets $\{|X-Y|>(1/n)\}\in\mathcal F$, which your notation does not quite reflect. Also, instead of $$P(\lim_{n\to\infty}(|X-Y|>(1/n))),$$ it would be more formally correct (or at least more common notation) to write $$P\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\{|X-Y|>(1/n)\}\right).$$
Other than that, your solution is fine.

Comment: Yeah, of course, thank You

Comment: Then why did you un-accept the answer again? Is there a problem?

Comment: No problem at all, just a mistake, I didn't realize. Now I realize, thanks again!

Comment: Alright, thanks. But don't hesitate to ask if anything is still unclear. :-)